# Javascript async/await in for loop

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have a problem

```
async function checkOk(listNotOkLocation) {
    // console.log(listNotOkLocation)
    var lenNotOk = listNotOkLocation.length
    if (lenNotOk == 0) return 'green'
    var latMarker = markerLocation.getPosition().lat()
    var lngMarker = markerLocation.getPosition().lng()
    var origin = latMarker.toString() + ", " + lngMarker.toString()

    for (var i = 0; i < lenNotOk; i++) {
        var lat = listNotOkLocation[i].lat
        var lng = listNotOkLocation[i].lng
        var destination = lat.toString() + ", " + lng.toString()
        calcRoute(origin,destination, function (err, dist) {
            console.log(1)
            if (!err) {        
                if (dist <= minDistance) 
                    return 'red'
            }
        });
    }
    console.log(2)
    return 'green'
}
```

Function calcRoute in for loop takes time, so function checkOk always returns 'green'. Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Putting `async` in front of a function allows you to use `await` in the function, but you can only await things that return promises. `calcRoute` takes a callback so it's not going to work unless you do something else or wrap it in a promise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wrap your `calcRoute` into something that returns a promise

```
function calcRouteP(origin, destination) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    calcRoute(origin, destination, function (err, dist) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(dist);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Then use it in your async function

```
async function checkOk(listNotOkLocation) {
    // console.log(listNotOkLocation)
    var lenNotOk = listNotOkLocation.length
    if (lenNotOk == 0) return 'green'
    var latMarker = markerLocation.getPosition().lat()
    var lngMarker = markerLocation.getPosition().lng()
    var origin = latMarker.toString() + ", " + lngMarker.toString()

    for (var i = 0; i < lenNotOk; i++) {
        var lat = listNotOkLocation[i].lat
        var lng = listNotOkLocation[i].lng
        var destination = lat.toString() + ", " + lng.toString()
        var dist = await calcRouteP(origin,destination);
        if (dist <= minDistance) {
          return 'red'
        }
    }
    console.log(2)
    return 'green'
}
```

note that for functions who's last argument is a callback that is passed `err, result` like your `calcRoute` function there are often libraries to do the wrapping for you. In node.js instead of wrapping `calcRoute` yourself you can do this

```
const util = require('util');
const calcRouteP = util.promisifiy(calcRoute);
```